# How to make zAccordion jQuery plugin responsive

Tags: jquery

Can any one guide me on how to make the zAccordion jQuery plugin for image slider responsive?

It is the just the appropriate image slider jquery plugin that I was looking for but unfortunately it is not responsive.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any one with the solution as yet?

Comment: Any solution to this one?